# C - 2d array not being initialised with zeros

Tags: c, arrays

Example A: `length` is some integer variable

```
int values[length][2];
```

This array will not have all the elements inside as zeros.

Example B:

```
int values[10][2];
```

This one will be all set to zeros.

My main question is how can I make the first one be initialized as zeros?

But, I would like if someone could explain why is the behavior different?

Comment: If they are local variables (the first one must be), then *neither* is initiliased to any value. You can explicitly intialise the second one with `int values[10][2] = { 0 };` but not the first. You must use `memset` or loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variable defined in block scope (i.e. inside of a function or an enclosing block) is not implicitly initialized.  It's values are **indeterminate**.  This is the case with both of your examples.  Just because the values happened to be 0 doesn't mean they were initialized.

If the array is question is *not* a variable length array, you could initialize it like this:

```
int values[10][2] = {{ 0 }};
```

This explicitly initializes one element of the 2D array to 0, and implicitly initializes the rest to 0.

A VLA however cannot be explicitly initialized.  So you should use `memset` to set the bytes to 0.

```
int values[length][2];
memset(values, 0, sizeof values);
```

Comment: Can you do `sizeof values` here? Unknown at compile time.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it's a local array, so it gets the size of the array.  Also, because it is a VLA, the `sizeof` operator is evaluated at run time instead of compile time.

Comment: I deleted the comment because i just noticed my mistake... You're completely correct, usage of `memset` does exactly what I was asking for

Comment: just in another note: Is it indifferent the fact of the array being 2d? Is the behavior to be expected exactly the same in a 1d? @dbush

Comment: @walkman That's correct.  It applies to *any* variable regardless of type.

Comment: many thanks for the time!

Comment: Pedantic, but, the scope does not matter - it just affects the identifier visibility - only the **storage duration matters**. You can **(almost) always** define a variable with static storage duration where you could define one with automatic. The only exceptions that come to mind are for loop initialization and function parameters.

Answer (score 3):

try using calloc it intialises junk of memory to 0's

Answer (score 0):

the thing is, it might be initialized by 0's if you are lucky and depending on the compiler you use.
The easiest might be:

memset(values, '\0', sizeof(int) * length * 2);